# Chartjs chart not showing

Tags: javascript, laravel, chart.js, laravel-blade, cdn

I have a multiple charts that I want to display on this blade file but it seems that only one chart can display..I need to display 4.. I've checked the developer console and there are no errors pertaining to this issue where might I be going wrong? I'm trying to use chartjs3.0.1

On chartjs 2 this seems to work but when I tried using later version this issue has come up

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-HJ+fjW1Hyzl79N1FHXTVgXGost+3N5d1i3rr6URACJItm5CjhEVy2UWlNNmFPHgX94k1RMrGACdmGgVi0vptrw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script> -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

 <!-------------- TOP 3 CROP COMMODITIES BY PRODUCTION VALUE --------------->

 <script>
    // Declaring variables for data to be used in graph as well as the url to pull from
    const url = "{{url('top3cropcomms')}}";
    const crop_sum = new Array();
    const crop_comm = new Array();
    // Create a document.ready function so the chart loads as soon as the page is opened
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // GET function for bringing the values from database into the variables listed above
      $.get(url, function(response){
        response.forEach(function(data){
            crop_comm.push(data.commodity);
            crop_sum.push(data.com_sum);
        });
        // setup 
        const data = {
        labels: crop_comm,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Weekly Sales',
            data: crop_sum,
            backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
        };

        // config 
        const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
            }
        }
        };

        // render init block
        const top3Crop_Chart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('top3cropcomm'),
        config
        );
      });
    });
</script>

<!-------------- TOP 3 LIVESTOCK COMMODITIES BY PRODUCTION VALUE --------------->

<script>
    const ls_comms_url = "{{url('top3lscomms')}}";
    const ls_sum = new Array();
    const ls_comm = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.get(ls_comms_url, function(response){
        response.forEach(function(data){
            ls_comm.push(data.commodity);
            ls_sum.push(data.com_sum);
        });
        // setup 
    const top3ls_data = {
      labels: ls_comm,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: ls_sum,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const  top3ls_config = {
      type: 'bar',
      top3ls_data,
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const top3LS_Chart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('top3lscomm'),
      top3ls_config
    );

            
      });
    });
</script>

<!-------------- CROP TRADE DATA --------------->

<script>
    const crop_trade_url = "{{url('croptradedata')}}";
    const crop_total_value = new Array();
    const year = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.get(crop_trade_url, function(response){
        response.forEach(function(data){
            crop_total_value.push(data.crop_total_value);
            year.push(data.year);
        });
        // setup 
    const croptrade_data = {
      labels: year,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Weekly Sales',
        data: crop_total_value,
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
          'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    };

    // config 
    const  croptrade_config = {
      type: 'bar',
      croptrade,
      options: {
        indexAxis: 'y',
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      }
    };

    // render init block
    const top3LS_Chart = new Chart(
      document.getElementById('croptrade'),
      croptrade_config
    );

            
      });
    });
</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

**check steps :**

Check your HTML structure: Ensure that you have four separate containers (e.g., `<canvas>` elements) in your blade file to hold each chart. Make sure you have unique IDs for each container, such as `top3cropcomm`, `top3lscomm`, and `croptrade`. Double-check that these IDs match the IDs used in your JavaScript code when initializing the charts.

Check your JavaScript configurations: Pay attention to the variable names you use for each chart's data and configuration objects. It appears that you have mistakenly assigned the chart configurations to the `top3ls_config` and `croptrade_config` variables, but you're initializing the charts with `top3LS_Chart` instead of `top3ls_chart` and `top3LS_Chart` again.

Verify the data retrieval and formatting: Ensure that the data you retrieve from the URLs (`url`, `ls_comms_url`, `crop_trade_url`) is correct and properly formatted. Double-check the property names (`commodity`, `com_sum`, `crop_total_value`, `year`) to match the actual response structure.

Check for JavaScript errors: Even if you don't see any errors in the console, it's a good idea to inspect the network requests in the browser's developer tools. Make sure the requests to retrieve the data from the URLs (`url`, `ls_comms_url`, `crop_trade_url`) are successful and return the expected data. If any errors occur during the requests, it might prevent the charts from being displayed.

Comment: The edit applied was a valid formatting improvement; why vandalize your post be reverting?